# Java spring - "required int parameter is not present"

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, controller

I'm new in Spring. I am trying to create editUser.jsp for purpose of editing user in mysql database. 
For that reason, I created controller and method for passing data from userList.jsp form to editUser.jsp.
Here is the code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/editUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
private String editUser(@RequestParam int id, Model model) {
    Users user = (Users) session.load(Users.class, id);
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("user");
    model.addAttribute("user", user);
    if(user.getId()!=null){
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        session.update(user);
        transaction.commit();
    }
    return "editUser";
}
```

And data are well passed to the editUser page. Now, when I try to edit and submit data I got error message:
*Required int parameter 'id' is not present*

```
<form:form action="editUser.htm" method="GET" commandName="editUser">
    <div>Account Information</div>
    <div>
        <form:label path="uname">User name:</form:label><br/>
        <form:input id="uname" type="text" path="uname"></form:input><br/>
        <form:label path="pass">Password:</form:label><br/>
        <form:input id="pass" type="text" path="pass"></form:input><br/>
        </div>

        <br/><br/>

        <div>Contact Information</div>
        <div>
        <form:label path="gender">Choose gender:</form:label><br/>
        <form:select id="gender" type="text" path="gender">
            <form:option value="Female">Female</form:option>
            <form:option selected="selected" value="Male">Male</form:option>
        </form:select><br/>
        <form:label path="age">Age:</form:label><br/>
        <form:input id="age" type="text" path="age"></form:input><br/>
        <form:label path="age">Address:</form:label><br/>
        <form:input id="address" type="text" path="address"></form:input><br/>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Edit User"/>
</form:form>enter code here
```

Do I need maybe create another method in the controller which should handle update data in the database or update handling could be done in existing method (currently, I'm totaly confused how jsp page "know" which method from Controller would be called)? 
Database column id is set - auto increment.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: <form:label path="age">Address:</form:label><br/> shouldnt it say path="adress" ?

Comment: Yes, thank you. But problem still exist.

Comment: You're confusing `input[id]` and `input[name]`. [Review the documentation for the tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input), and learn to look at your browser's Network developer tab to see the actual request being sent.

Answer (score 0):

@RequestParam(value="id",required="false") int id